# TerraformTaskV4 defaulting to use_msi=true as it is unable to get service principal credentials from the service connection

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

I have my IaC terraform code on GitHub and I am trying to create an IaC pipeline on Azure pipelines. I have my task below

```
- task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-installer-task.TerraformInstaller@0
  inputs:
    terraformVersion: '1.3.7'

- task: TerraformTaskV4@4
  inputs:
    provider: 'azurerm'
    command: 'init'
    backendServiceArm: 'Svc Conn Name'
    backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'terraform-statefile'
    backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'XXX'
    backendAzureRmContainerName: 'devtfstatecontainer'
    backendAzureRmKey: 'tfstate'
```

But I get below:

```
Starting: TerraformTaskV4
==============================================================================
Task         : Terraform
Description  : Execute terraform commands to manage resources on AzureRM, Amazon Web Services(AWS) and Google Cloud Platform(GCP)
Version      : 4.218.21
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [Learn more about this task](https://aka.ms/AAf0uqr)
==============================================================================
/opt/hostedtoolcache/terraform/1.3.7/x64/terraform init -backend-config=storage_account_name=XXX -backend-config=container_name=XXX -backend-config=key=tfstate -backend-config=resource_group_name=XXX -backend-config=subscription_id=XXX -backend-config=tenant_id=XXX -backend-config=use_msi=true


Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: Error retrieving keys for Storage Account "tfstate": azure.BearerAuthorizer#WithAuthorization: Failed to refresh the Token for request to https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/XXXX/resourceGroups/XXX/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/XXX/listKeys?api-version=2021-01-01: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: adal: Refresh request failed. Status Code = '400'. Response body: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Identity not found"} Endpoint http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F
│ 
│ 
╵

##[error]Error: The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/terraform/1.3.7/x64/terraform' failed with exit code 1
```

I have traced it back to [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-terraform/blob/59a97b0b9c7c857953e5238667444dcaf15eb8e5/Tasks/TerraformTask/TerraformTaskV4/src/azure-terraform-command-handler.ts#L27). However I do not understand why it wouldn't get the credentials from the service connection.

Context

1. My IaC code lives in Github
2. I have a service connection on Azure Pipeline using Service Principal credentials (manually)

I have verified that the pipeline has permission to use the service connection.